# Flex 3 - How to define 2 states and transition between them?

Tags: apache-flex, animation, flex3, transition, states

My first steps with Flex (currently using Flex 3) and I want to define 2 states where in the first I have a list and a panel with some button bellow it. When clicking one of the buttons in that panel, I'm expecting to change the state to the "ListState". How should I define which component bellong to which state in this case?
How can I also animate the transition between them by enlarging the list and "move" the panel down outside the application?
The expected behavior is presented in the following picture: [image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve This without States. As I have understood your task. I will suggest you to use `Canvas`  with 100% height and width. inside canvas You use `List` and `Panel`

List will
`<mx:List id="List" height="{cnvas.height-panel.height}" width="100%"/>`

panel will `<mx:Pannel id="panel" height="300" y="{cnvas.height-panel.height}" width="100%" paddingTop="10">`

Now When you click button set `slideUP.play()` and  `pannel.height=0`.

Addition to this you have to set annimation:
`<mx:AnimateProperty id="slideUP"  target="{panel}" property="y" 
fromValue="{cnvas.height-panel.height}" toValue="{cnvas.height}" duration="400" />`